# Convert to "native" swift data type

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting some data from firestore. The problem is that they are in a format that I don't know how to use. This is the data I
receive:

> "["TestKey3": <__NSArrayM 0x600002d30b10>(
> ArrayElement1,
> ArrayElement2,
> ArrayElement3
> )
> , "TestKey5": 12345, "TestKey4": 1, "TestKey2": TestValue2, "TestKey1": TestValue1]
> "

And this is the data type:"DataType: Dictionary<String, Any>". Dictionary seems okay normal. I can use dictionary as normal. I need to unwrap Optional and then it is okay.

5 is Int, 4 is Bool, 3 is array, 2 and 1 is string.

The problem is is the array. Even though I have have unwrapped the dictionary, I need to unwrap the array again. It is a __NSArrayM, so I can't use it as a native/swift array, which I want, like using append(). How do I convert it?

This is the script:

```
static func getData(collectionName: String, documentName: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection(collectionName).document(documentName)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data()
            guard var output = dataDescription else {
               return
            }
            print("Getting data at: /\(collectionName)/\(documentName)")
            print("DataType: \(type(of: output))")
            print(output)
        } else {
            print("Error getting data at: /\(collectionName)/\(documentName)")
        }
    }
}`
```

I want to use "completion: @escaping ([String: Any]?) -> Void)" on the function, so it can wait, but don't know what exactly it should be.

Comment: Why can't you use a native array, what happens?

Comment: It is a NSArrayM. If I for example use append() it doesn't work, because it is not a "native" swift array.

Comment: Oh so you have trie to use the type directly, I thought you had at least tried to cast it to a swift array. Can't you try to cast it as `as? [Any]` or the actual type if you now it?

Comment: I found a solution: var array = output[key] as AnyObject as! [String]
                        output[key] = array